# Making one field equal to another in the same Attribute table using Field calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I am trying to have a new field with the same content of an existing field.

In ArcGIS I would normally use the Field Calculator to make this instantly.

In QGIS I have followed the same steps (create new field, open field calculator, make it equal to an existing field) but it doesn't work... meaning nothing changes, the new field remains empty...

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Please give us a clue, what doesn't work? How do you make it equal to an existing field?

Comment: If you want to set `field 2` equal to `field 1` you use `"field 1"` in the field calculator.

Answer (score 3):

First check that edit mode is turned on. Then instead of putting into the expression window **PercentTF = Wards_wi_6** as you currently have it, just put "Wards_wi_6" (i.e. enclosed in double quotes") and press ok. You have already specified in the upper dialogue box where you want the result.

Answer (score 1):

If a new layer can/may be created instead of changing the existing one, there is a possibility using the ['Refactor fields'](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields) tool.

Input layer:
[image: input]

Refactor fields:
[image: rf_menu]

Output layer:
[image: output]